# Can't start mysql service using Homebrew

Tags: mysql, homebrew, macos-sonoma

I'm having issues in starting the mysql services which I have installed using homebrew.
I'm currently working on a Mac, running MacOS Sonoma 14.0.

The service itself should be installed correctly.
At least when I run brew services list, the service is showing.
I have not experienced any errors during (my last) installation.

**brew services list**

| Name | Status | User | File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dnsmasq | none | root |  |
| httpd | started | my username | ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist |
| mysql | stopped | root | ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist |
| nginx | none | root |  |
| php@8.2 | none | root |  |

However, when I try to start the service I get the following error message:

**brew services start mysql**

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/myusername/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` exited with 5.

I've tried several possible sollutions I've found on the web but nothing worked for me.
At this point I don't know what I could do to resolve this issue.
Any help would be great. Thank you in advance!